# How can I get conditional execution in jUnit when using Theories?

Tags: java, junit

I have an abstract test case using the `Theories` runner which tests an interface.  Each implementation of the interface has a concrete implementation of the test case, and one of those implementations uses Postgres.  I'd like to make that test case only run if a connection to a Postgres database is actually available and be ignored otherwise.

I can't use `Assume` because the `Theories` test runner will fail if all of the data points for a theory fail their assumptions.

I'm testing a ResourceStore which is essentially a simple file system.  It takes paths and returns Resource objects, which may be backed by the file system, or by something else like Postgres.  I'm using Theories to test that the resources returned follow certain rules so that the implementations are consistent with one another.

The base class looks like this (imports and most of the specific tests trimmed)

```
/**
 * JUnit Theory test class for Resource invariants. Subclasses should provide representative 
 * DataPoints to test.
 * 
 */
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public abstract class ResourceTheoryTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    protected abstract Resource getResource(String path) throws Exception;

    @Theory
    public void theoryNotNull(String path) throws Exception {
        Resource res = getResource(path);

        assertThat(res, notNullValue());
    }

    @Theory
    public void theoryExtantHaveDate(String path) throws Exception {
        Resource res = getResource(path);

        assumeThat(res, defined());

        long result = res.lastmodified();

        assertThat(result, notNullValue());
    }

}
```

The file system based implementation creates a temporary directory, sets it up with some files, and then hits the store being tested with paths, some existing, some not.

```
public class FileSystemResourceTheoryTest extends ResourceTheoryTest {

    FileSystemResourceStore store;

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();


    @DataPoints
    public static String[] testPaths() {
        return new String[]{"FileA","FileB", "DirC", "DirC/FileD", "DirE", "UndefF", "DirC/UndefF", "DirE/UndefF", "DirE/UndefG/UndefH/UndefI"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Resource getResource(String path) throws Exception{
        return store.get(path);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        folder.newFile("FileA");
        folder.newFile("FileB");
        File c = folder.newFolder("DirC");        
        (new File(c, "FileD")).createNewFile();
        folder.newFolder("DirE");
        store = new FileSystemResourceStore(folder.getRoot());
    }

}
```

The JDBC based module has another abstract test case based on the first, which uses a TestSupport delegate to abstract the dialect differences in connecting to and setting up the test environment. The same support class is used for other non-theory tests as well.

```
public abstract class AbstractJDBCResourceTheoryTest extends ResourceTheoryTest {

    DatabaseTestSupport support;

    @DataPoints
    public static String[] testPaths() {
        return new String[]{"FileA","FileB", "DirC", "DirC/FileD", "DirE", "UndefF", "DirC/UndefF", "DirE/UndefF"/*, "DirE/UndefG/UndefH/UndefI"*/};
    }

    protected JDBCResourceStoreProperties mockConfig(boolean enabled, boolean init) {
        JDBCResourceStoreProperties config = createMock(JDBCResourceStoreProperties.class);

        expect(config.isInitDb()).andStubReturn(init);
        expect(config.isEnabled()).andStubReturn(enabled);
        expect(config.isImport()).andStubReturn(init);

        support.stubConfig(config);

        return config;
    }

    protected DataSource testDataSource() throws Exception {
        return support.getDataSource();
    }

    public AbstractJDBCResourceTheoryTest() {
        super();
    }

    protected void standardData() throws Exception {
        support.initialize();

        support.addFile("FileA", 0, "FileA Contents".getBytes());
        support.addFile("FileB", 0, "FileB Contents".getBytes());
        int c = support.addDir("DirC", 0);
        support.addFile("FileD", c, "FileD Contents".getBytes());
        support.addDir("DirE", 0);
    }

    Integer getInt(ResultSet rs, String column) throws Exception {
        int i = rs.getInt(column);
        if(rs.wasNull()) return null;
        return i;
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() throws Exception {
        support.close();
    }
}
```

The Postgres test case just plugs in the Postgres test support module and uses it to initialize the test framework and the Resource Store being tested.  It currently connects to the database for each datapoint of each test although I plan to fix that.

```
public class PostgresJDBCResourceTheoryTest extends AbstractJDBCResourceTheoryTest {

    JDBCResourceStore store;

    @Override
    protected Resource getResource(String path) throws Exception{
        return store.get(path);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        support = new PostgresTestSupport();

        standardData();

        JDBCResourceStoreProperties config = mockConfig(true, false);
        replay(config);

        store = new JDBCResourceStore(support.getDataSource(), config);
    }
}
```

There's also an H2 implementation with a test that works the same way but using an in memory H2 database.

Comment: As I demonstrated in my answer, your `@DataPoints` method has to be the point at which you check connection status. Given your updated code, you need to have a single always-valid resource to test against.

The correct solution to what you're trying to do is to implement your own runner. I say correct because that's how you do it without trying to fight against `JUnit`'s architecture. But that might be more trouble than you care to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a clue what your code looks like, I made a bunch of assumptions and created an example that seems to support your intent.

```
import org.junit.experimental.theories.*;

@org.junit.runner.RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryTest {
    // this is one possible way to store the setting:
    private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> postgresConnected = new ThreadLocal<>();
    static interface Under {}
    static class Over implements Under {}
    static class Through implements Under {}
    static { postgresConnected.set(true); } // this logic belongs somewhere else

    @DataPoints
    public static Under[] underData() {
        if (postgresConnected.get())
            return new Under[] { new Over(), new Through() };
        return new Under[] { new Over() };
    }

    @Theory
    public void testUnder(Under under) {
        System.out.println(under.getClass());
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(under);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't meet your needs, post a little more detail and I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that will work though as I have multiple subclasses of an abstract test case class for the different implementations. Some are in separate modules which may not always be built, and when they are built, a Postgres instance may not be available, but the rest of the test cases still need to run.  I'll update the question when I have a bit more time.

Comment: Yeah, more detail in the question would help, because I think all of those cases can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use ThreadLocal.

It is a mechanism which allows you to set specific Thread variables, and in your case you can deliver the Postgres connection using the ThreadLocal and know according the the existence of the connection whether or not to run the specific test.

This post contains a simple example of how to use [Java ThreadLocal](http://www.usepatterns.com/1/post/2014/03/java-threadlocal-good-or-bad-design-decision.html)

Comment: It's not getting the existence of a Postgres connection to the tests that's a problem, it's turning off the tests when that connection isn't available.  Normally I'd use Assume, but the Theories runner fails if a theory fails its assumptions for all data points rather than ignoring the test as would normally happen.  Ideally I want a way to get that same runtime ignore behaviour with the Theories test runner.

Answer (score 0):

Given your updated question, here's what you're doing wrong: you're trying to use `@DataPoints` that are defined before your `@Before` (set-up) code. As I said in my comment, you're fighting the `JUnit` architecture. `@DataPoints` are defined statically, but your database connection is defined per-test, after the fact. As shown in my original answer, it is (absolutely?) essential that the `@DataPoints` vary based on connection status, which does not happen in your code sample.

Nevertheless, I have a working solution. Since theories require at least one valid datapoint, I created a fallback that is always valid, and use it whenever no connection is present. The code is posted in reverse order, but does indeed compile and run (when snips are restored from the question).

```
public class PostgresJDBCResourceTheoryTest extends AbstractJDBCResourceTheoryTest {
    static JDBCResourceStore store;

    protected Resource getResource(String path) throws Exception {
        if (path == "AlwaysValidResource")
            return ALWAYS_VALID;
        return store.get(path);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        . . .
        store = new JDBCResourceStore(support.getDataSource(), config);
        connect();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        disconnect();
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractJDBCResourceTheoryTest extends ResourceTheoryTest {
    private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> connected = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @DataPoints
    public static String[] testPaths() {
        if (connected.get() == null || ! connected.get())
            return new String[]{"AlwaysValidResource"};
        return new String[]{"FileA", "FileB", "DirC", "DirC/FileD", "DirE", "UndefF", "DirC/UndefF", "DirE/UndefF"/*, "DirE/UndefG/UndefH/UndefI"*/};
    }

    static void connect() {
        connected.set(true);
    }
    static void disconnect() {
        connected.set(false);
    }
  }

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public abstract class ResourceTheoryTest {
    public static final Resource ALWAYS_VALID = new AlwaysValidResource();
    . . .
}
```